# Removing IP Address From Files On Site (IIS)

Tags: domain, files, mask

I have an IIS server set up hosting my website (only 2 files now: `index.htm` and `banner.png`). I have a domain set up with GoDaddy and have forwarding set up in GoDaddy as well.

So, when I type `http://example.com`, it takes me straight to the index.htm page with the IP masked in the address bar (shows `http://example.com`).

If I right-click on the banner at the top of my homepage, the URL from that banner is `http://ip/banner.png`. I want this to be `http://example.com/banner.png`. How do I do this?

Is this something I set up through GoDaddy or IIS?

Answer (score 1):

Probably your `index.htm` file says something like this:

```
<img src="http://198.51.100.42/banner.png" />
```

Change it to say:

```
<img src="http://example.com/banner.png" />
```

Or simply:

```
<img src="banner.png" />
```